# Compatibilty issue between Hibernate 3 and Hibernate 4

Tags: java, hibernate

My problem is in my application , existing applications use hibernate 3 compatible `LocalSessionFactory` Bean, But while integrating with another module which is using hibernate4 compatible `LocalSessionFactory` Bean,
Now I have to integrate both and the problem is I can't change existing code.
please privide any solution which solve this compatibilty issue.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [commons.hibernate.TableShardAwareLocalSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'uidMasterV1SessionFactory' defined in class path resource [packaged/spring/v1_1/uidmaster-spring-config-true.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1269)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:901)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:94)
    at server.impl.bootstrapext.spring.ApplicationContextFactory.init(ApplicationContextFactory.java:162)
    at server.impl.container.ContainerImpl$BootstrapExtensionDependencyManager.loadBootstrapExtension(ContainerImpl.java:350)
    at server.impl.container.ContainerImpl$BootstrapExtensionDependencyManager.checkAndloadBootstrapExtension(ContainerImpl.java:305)
    at server.impl.container.ContainerImpl$BootstrapExtensionDependencyManager.loadBootstrapExtensions(ContainerImpl.java:280)
    at server.impl.container.ContainerImpl.initializeBootstrapExtensions(ContainerImpl.java:165)
    at server.impl.container.ContainerImpl.init(ContainerImpl.java:101)
    at server.bootstrap.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:230)
    at server.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:109)
    at server.bootstrap.BootStrapServlet.init(BootStrapServlet.java:95)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5554)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBean
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:260)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1258)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 41 more
Fatal error in bootstrap sequence. Cannot continue!
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [commons.hibernate.TableShardAwareLocalSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'uidMasterV1SessionFactory' defined in class path resource [packaged/spring/v1_1/uidmaster-spring-config-true.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1269)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:901)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:94)
    at server.impl.bootstrapext.spring.ApplicationContextFactory.init(ApplicationContextFactory.java:162)
    at server.impl.container.ContainerImpl$BootstrapExtensionDependencyManager.loadBootstrapExtension(ContainerImpl.java:350)
    at server.impl.container.ContainerImpl$BootstrapExtensionDependencyManager.checkAndloadBootstrapExtension(ContainerImpl.java:305)
    at server.impl.container.ContainerImpl$BootstrapExtensionDependencyManager.loadBootstrapExtensions(ContainerImpl.java:280)
    at server.impl.container.ContainerImpl.initializeBootstrapExtensions(ContainerImpl.java:165)
    at server.impl.container.ContainerImpl.init(ContainerImpl.java:101)
    at server.bootstrap.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:230)
    at server.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:109)
    at server.bootstrap.BootStrapServlet.init(BootStrapServlet.java:95)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5554)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBean
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:260)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1258)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 41 more
```

Comment: Is this a typo: `TableShardAwareLocalSessionFactoryBean` ?

Comment: @vikingsteve no its not a typo its the class which extends LocalSessionFactoryBean